# How to sort the following array?

Tags: php, sorting

I am fetching records from database which returns an array as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => ravi
        [text] => hey
        [date] => 2011-05-1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object

    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => shiv
        [text] => bye
        [date] => 2011-04-29
    )

[2] => stdClass Object

    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => adi
        [text] => hello
        [date] => 2011-04-30
    )
)
```

How to sort this based on the date element?

Answer (score 3):

You should sort this before you actually fetch it, meaning use the 'ORDER BY' clause already in your database query!

Why?

- because you write much less code
- because it is faster
- because it is easier to refactor

Comment: and dont forget to add an index for the date field

Comment: Thanks markus, But actually i can't use order by clause. Bcoz it is inside another foreach loop and i am simply making an array of data inside it.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the `usort()` function useful: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You could pass in as the second parameter the following function:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->date == $b->date) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->date < $b->date) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: you might actually need this http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php then use the above function with $arrayObject->uasort('cmp'); however you should also convert the dates to timestamp before directly comparing with < and >

Comment: Yeah, or write a heavy framework for sorting arrays coming directly from the DB... :P

Comment: @venimus you're right, I erroneously assumed they were strings: in that case the string operators (<,>) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be sorting within the query itself, using  `...ORDER BY`date`..`

..but if you really wanna do it with php, look at the user notes in the manual under [sort](http://www.php.net/sort), there are examples of how to sort like that (and you can apply with rsort() or asort() or arsort() depending on if you want to preserve keys or sort descending or whatever)